# Why is PyCharm still highlighting typos even though I unchecked that feature?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]

As you can see in the picture, I have unchecked the spelling field. But for some reason it still puts this green "^^^^^^^^" under "wrong" spelled words.
Which is very annoying.

What am I supposed to do, did I remove the green lines incorrectly?

Comment: Which version of pycharms you use?

Comment: community edition 2016.3

Comment: Did you try clicking OK? Even if you click Apply, it won't update the editor until you click OK.

Comment: yes.. I also just tried to uncheck everything. And its like nothing changed

Comment: Make sure you're editing Settings, and not Default Settings. Changing the default settings has no immediate effect on the editor. And try closing and re-opening the program, too, if you haven't already.

Comment: Ah thats it! I pressed default settings, instead of editing settings. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @RandomDavis This would be a good comment to be an part of an Answer, coupled with the actual setting.

Comment: @ChrisLarson He doesn't need to know the actual setting, he already found it as you can see in his screenshot. Unless you mean that it would help future readers. Regardless, I put it in my answer.

Comment: @RandomDavis I did mean for future readers, yeah. Good job on identifying the problem! I figured you should get full credit for the win. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(converting my comments to an answer)

From your screenshot, you clearly did click on the correct setting. There were two things I thought this could be. One of them was that, based on your screenshot, I wasn't sure if you had previously clicked OK on the menu, or if you had just clicked Apply. It turns out that if you click Apply, it doesn't actually take effect anyway until you click OK.

The second one (which it ended up being), was that there is a menu in Pycharm identical to the settings menu - the Default Settings menu. If you make changes there, they have no effect. In order for settings to immediately take effect, you have to edit them in the actual Settings menu (which can be opened with CTRL+ALT+S on Windows). Then, the setting is Editor -> Code Style -> Inspections -> Spelling -> Typo. You already knew that, though.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable Typo inspection. You can find more information [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html)
Also here is more information on how [spell check](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/spellchecking.html) works

Comment: He did disable it, that's what's in his screenshot. His problem was that it didn't take effect. And that was because he was editing default settings instead of settings.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your left panel menu, I think you may be modifying future project "Default Settings" and not current project "Settings". In order to apply the changes to your currently opened project you need to go to save the inspection profile and click "copy to project".

If all else fails you can hard-code the changes in the xmls.

- Project_Default.xml file is located in the
  /.idea/inspectionProfiles directory.
- Default.xml is stored locally in the Default.xml file under the
  USER_HOME/./config/inspection directory.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get rid of spell checking in PyCharm is to deactivate the "Grazie Lite" plugin which does "Intelligent spelling and grammar checks for any text you write in the IDE."

Personally I don't see any intelligent behaviour in spell-checking **code**. For instance, if I simulate Michaelis-Menten kinetics, then I have every right in the world to call one of the variables `vmax` ([Wikipedia explains the background)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics). Which was prompty flagged as a "typo" by this oh-so-intelligent spell checker.

Spell checkers should be an opt-in for the alphabetically challenged among us. But discussing this would take us too far so I rather stop here.